# dbDelta not CREATING TABLE

Tags: plugins, mysql, dbdelta

Here's my code. 
Please help

```
function lapizzeria_database() {
   global $wpdb;

   global $lapizzeria_db_version;
   $lapizzeria_db_version = "1.0";

   $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'reservation';

   $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

   //SQL Statement

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        date datetime NOT NULL,
        email varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        phone varchar(10) NOT NULL
        message longtext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
   ) $charset_collate; ";

   require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
   dbDelta($sql);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'lapizzeria_database');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing comma end of `phone varchar(10) NOT NULL` line, add comma end of line  after that table will be created. I have tested https://prnt.sc/qgqmog

```
function lapizzeria_database() {
   global $wpdb;

   global $lapizzeria_db_version;
   $lapizzeria_db_version = "1.0";

   $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'reservation';

   $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

   //SQL Statement

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        date datetime NOT NULL,
        email varchar(50) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        phone varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        message longtext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
   ) $charset_collate; ";

   require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
   dbDelta($sql);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'lapizzeria_database');
```